# Regular Expression to match account number consisting of specific 3 character string followed by 9 digits

Tags: regex

I'm trying to craft a regular expression which will match an account number which consists of specific 3 characters strings followed by 9 digits.
e.g.

```
abc123456789
xyz123456789
def987654321
```

I've figured out how to accomplish with the following expression but wanted to know if there was a better way:

```
abc[0-9]{9}|xyz[0-9]{9}|def[0-9]{9}
```

Comment: If you are validating a form field also consider to wrap your regexp with `^` and `$` otherwise something like `ievilabc12345678988788` will also match the regexp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the OR only for the specific strings since it is the only one thing changing:

```
(abc|xyz|def)[0-9]{9}
```

Comment: As far as it is matching a field it would be a good idea to wrap the expression with `^` and `$`

Answer (score 1):

If the account number can only consist of `abc`, `def` or `xyz`, you can use `|` specifically for those strings, as pointed out by Jorge Campos:

```
(abc|def|xyz)\d{9}
```

However, assuming it can start with any combination of non-numerical characters, this is the most compact way to put it:

```
\D{3}\d{9}
```